# How to check for length of a git command's output in groovy?

Tags: git, groovy

I have something like this in my shell script

```
if  [ -z "$(git status --porcelain)" ];
    then 
         echo "something"
```

How do I implement it in Groovy?

I tried something like this but it does not quite work

```
def p1 = "git status --porcelain".execute(null, workingDir)
p1.waitFor()
if (p1.length() != 0 ) {
     println "something"
}
```

Comment: it's `p1.text.length()`

Comment: Just in case. There is https://github.com/ajoberstar/grgit . "The Groovy way to use Git. "

Answer (score 2):

For a short version you can do something like:

```
'/usr/bin/git status --porcelain'.execute().text.readLines().each { line -> 
    println "log line: $line"
}
```

where the .text call waits for the process to complete so the waitFor is not required. Note the full path to the git executable.